# Could not find required file 'setup.bin'

Tags: visual-studio, .net-4.0

I'm unable to build a Setup Project in VS2010, for a Windows Service project. It fails with this error:

> Could not find required file 'setup.bin' in 'C:\MyProject\Engine'.

My environment is *Windows 7 Professional x64* with *Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel*

I've downloaded [Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279), repaired, then rebooted, then installed the unchecked components except Visual C++ compiler, then installed [KB2519277](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2519277).

These are the existing registry entries:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\GenericBootstrapper\3.5
    Path = c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\GenericBootstrapper\4.0
    Path = c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\
```

These are the existing files:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Engine\setup.bin

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Engine\setup.bin
```

An existing workaround is to copy the Engine directory to the project directory, however this has to be done every time you make a new project.

How can this be fixed properly?

Comment: Did you try to add this directories to Environment Value PATH?

Comment: @AtillaOzgur Just tried it, still getting the error.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With Process Monitor I found that, right before trying to access the path, a DLL is used to retrieve this path. The following may be borderline legal, but I'd like to share my findings anyway.

The DLL is located at `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll` and the class being used is `Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Deployment.Bootstrapper.BootstrapperBuilder`. Using your favourite disassembly tool, you can find that ultimately three attempts are made at retrieving the path.

1. HKLM\Software\Microsoft\GenericBootstrapper\11.0\Path
2. HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\GenericBootstrapper\11.0\Path
3. Environment.CurrentDirectory

I'm unsure why it says *11.0*, as far as I can remember VS 2012 has not been installed on this machine before.

So there's a bug in the SDK installer or there's a bug in the DLL. Either way, creating the *11.0* registry key and adding the value resolves this issue. Note: Visual Studio must be restarted, because after attempting to retrieve the path, it is cached.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\GenericBootstrapper\11.0]
"Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0A\\Bootstrapper\\"
```

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\GenericBootstrapper\11.0]
"Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0A\\Bootstrapper\\"
```

Comment: I had a similar issue, except I saw slightly different behaviour than you. I changed my MSBuild `ToolsVersion` to be `4.0` alike so: `<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://...` and it all worked fine without registry hackery.

Comment: Also @ta.speot.is... *how* did you change your MSBuild ToolsVersion?  What file are you editing?

Comment: I used the 2nd key (with "Wow6432Node") since I don't have "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\GenericBootstrapper".  I also changed v7.0A to v8.1A since I have Visual Studio 2013 Update 1

Comment: My fix using TFS builds with custom template: Open custom template, find task "Run MSBuild for Project"  Edit it's "ToolVersion" property to "12.0" (VS2013).  This matched the same prop in my projects XML and in my NuGet.targets files.  Only then will my build call the new MSBuild location (outside framework).  Why I had to manually change all these settings I've no idea.

Comment: This is still helpfull, but just a note that you don't need to use a dissassembler nowadays, is on GitHub: [GenerateBootsrapper.cs](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/c1459f5cbd36f2c33eafc8f4ff087f6ee84c3640/src/XMakeTasks/GenerateBootstrapper.cs)

Comment: the relevant file is [Util.cs](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/c1459f5cbd36f2c33eafc8f4ff087f6ee84c3640/src/XMakeTasks/BootstrapperUtil/Util.cs) which looks for current VS version key *or* the 'default' 4.0 key (eg. when build from SDK msbuild.exe it looks for 4.0).

Answer (score 19):

Before going down the rabbit hole, verify that you need the bootstrapper. If you do not, then you can turn it off by doing one of the following. This will also resolve the error.

**The GUI way:**

1. Right Click on the Project
2. Click `Properties`
3. Click the `Publish` Tab on the left
4. Click the `Prerequisites...` button
5. Uncheck `Create setup program to install prerequisite components`

[image: Project Properties]

This answer came from this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7672078f-f2bd-4142-b8a9-740c2a8a5ae7/clickonce-bootstrapper-files-without-installing-visual-studio?forum=msbuild).

**The manually edit `csproj` file way:**

1. Add `<BootstrapperEnabled>false</BootstrapperEnabled>` to the bottom of the first `<PropertyGroup>` element

Comment: Thanks - it can be also done by setting <BootstrapperEnabled>false</BootstrapperEnabled> directly inside csproj

Comment: @rudolf_franek where in the csproj should the `<BootstrapperEnabled/>` element be added?

Comment: Just at the end of the very first <PropertyGroup> in the csproj

Comment: @rudolf_franek thank you for letting me know. I updated the answer to help anyone else reading this in the future.

Answer (score 6):

This solution worked for me (VS 2013): http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2014/05/31/error-msb3147-could-not-find-required-file-setup-bin-in/

Change the PATH of the msbuild.exe to: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MsBuild\12.0\Bin\msbuild.EXE`

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with a TFS build.

You can resolve the problem by setting the visual studio version in the MSBuild arguments of the definition build:

```
/property:VisualStudioVersion=12.0;
```

[image: MSBuild arguments in build definition]

Answer (score 2):

It's a multi step solution.

First make sure you have the .Net SDKs installed.

Then make sure the following registry entry exists:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\GenericBootstrapper\11.0`

It must contain a 'Path' entry with the value pointing to the location of the bootstrapper: 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\Bootstrapper\`

The following powershell script does that for you:

```
$registryPath = "Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\GenericBootstrapper\11.0"
$registryValue = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\Bootstrapper\" 
function CreateRegistryValues {

    if(-not (Test-Path $registryPath ) )
    {
        Push-Location
        Set-Location -Path Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\GenericBootstrapper
        # First add the registry item
        New-Item -Name '11.0' -Value $registryValue
        #Then add a property on it for 'Path' and the folder in bootstrapper that contains the 'Engine' folder 
        New-ItemProperty `
            -Path  $registryPath `
            -Name 'Path' `
            -PropertyType String `
            -Value $registryValue
        Pop-Location
    }else{
        Write-Warning "You already have the registry key ($registryPath) set. `r`n No action was taken `r`n "
    }
}
```

Finally, you must copy the contents of the 'Engine' folder included as part of the Visual Studio tooling to the location listed in the registry value:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\Bootstrapper\"
```

Answer (score 0):

MY SOLUTION TO THE PROBLEM: cannot publish, because setup.bin cannot be found

When using the PUBLISH wizard in vs2008, the application cannot be published because setup.bin cannot be found.

---

The short answer is:

Paste the `engine` folder into the location that is indicated in the ERROR message in the vs2008 IDE.

The `engine` folder can be found in the `Microsoft SDKs` folder.

---

The long answer is:

In my case, vs2008 was looking for setup.bin in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\engine\`.

This location was indicated in the error within the vs2008 IDE.

The `engine` folder did not exist at the above location, because the `engine` folder was not there.

The `engine` folder was in fact at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Engine`.

This `engine` folder location was found by searching the registry for an occurrence of setup.bin

I copied the `engine` folder from `Microsoft SDKs` folder and pasted it into the `Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0` folder.

This folder copy resolved the problem and allowed me to publish an app.

Here are the specific steps I took:

1. Search the registry for setup.bin
2. When setup.bin is found in the registry, inspect the key and note the folder location of setup.bin (in my case this was `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Engine`)
3. In the VS2008 IDE, look in the ERROR window and note the folder location for the setup.bin error (in my case this was `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\engine\`)
4. The vs2008 IDE was expecting setup.bin to be in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\engine\`, but
   this `engine` folder did not exist
5. Copy the `engine` folder from `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Engine`, and paste this folder into the IDE folder at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\`

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this issue for a while.

The solution is quite simple. You have to install "clickonce build tools" in Visual Studio or Visual Studio Build Tools. It's a small component and normally is not auto-selected.

Comment: Are you sure this is the same problem OP was having? They were specific about their environment details.