# failed to publish: could not find required file 'setup.bin'

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.0, publish

I have a sample Console application testing the MySQL connectivity. The code is below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace MySQLConnection
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connStr = "server=localhost;user=root;database=world;port=3306;password=Password;";
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                conn.Open();

                string sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Country";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
                object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                if (result != null)
                {
                    int r = Convert.ToInt32(result);
                    Console.WriteLine("Number of countries in the World database is: " + r);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The code runs fine. But when I try to publish the project I get an error as shown in the image below.

[image: error description]

I am using VS2012 Update 3 targeting .NET 4. Any ideas?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Using this answer: [Could not find required file 'setup.bin'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139538/could-not-find-required-file-setup-bin) I was able to publish the application.

In my case it was that

1. HKLM\Software\Microsoft\GenericBootstrapper\11.0\Path does **not** exist.
2. HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\GenericBootstrapper\11.0\Path exists and points to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\Bootstrapper\`

From that directory I copied the `Engine` directory to my application directory and then was able to publish the app. Hopefully, this does not need to be done each time.

Answer (score -3):

I suggest you to correct your string connection with `userid property` and add @

```
var connStr = @"server=localhost;userid=root;database=world;port=3306;password=Password;";
```