# Visual Studio 2010 one click publishing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have finished my first program for work (`vb.net`). I'm not a professional programmer just creating a program as a side project at work.

I have come to build/publish my project and create the installer so I can install my program on other laptops that are going out with equipment.  I have ran into a problem as it will not publish.

I am actively searching the web for an answer as well but it all seems quite complicated.  Sorry I'm new to this and hopefully it is something quite simple.  I also have access to the laptops before they go so is there a way get a working `.exe` on these laptops and install the `.net` components I need manually.

Thank you for any responses I get.

```
Warning 2   Item '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client' could not be located in...
Warning 3   Item 'Microsoft.Windows.Installer.3.1' could not be located in...
Error   4   Could not find required file 'setup.bin' in...
```

Comment: i haven't really messed with installers at all, but I have a suggestion. Look at the project properties for each of your projects, and specifically at the target framework. change your target framework  to .Net Framework 4.0 not .Net Framework 4.0 Client Profile. Not sure it will work, but it looks like your problem is with the Client Profile.

Comment: I think @mmeasor has the right idea. If that answer doesn't work out for you I would also check that you actually have .NET 4.0 installed on these machines.  If not, you might a) install it b) target 3.5 instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  This didn't do anything, I have checked to make sure .net framework is installed but the errors keep coming up.  I think it is something to do with the bootstraper but I'm in over my head now with on one around to guide or teach me.  I'll keep trying and maybe reinstall VS2010.

Comment: Possibly look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139538/could-not-find-required-file-setup-bin.  Your warnings would not stop the build (but should be corrected somehow)

Comment: Thanks Jason (My name too btw hehe) it worked but the program when installed on the other machine keeps firing errors (Async pinging) from a try/catch and doesn't work.  It works perfectly on the deveopment machine.  Both environments are win7 .net 4 etc.