# Teamcity: error MSB3147: Could not find required file 'setup.bin'

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, teamcity, publish

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.target
error MSB3147: Could not find required file 'setup.bin' in ... folder

I have seen there are similar messages during the time frame of last upgrade of VS for 2012.

I did not find the registry keys on the build server as mentioned in other posts i.e. [Could not find required file 'setup.bin'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139538/could-not-find-required-file-setup-bin)

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

> Teamcity: error MSB3147: Could not find required file 'setup.bin'

According to [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/emmamou/2009/04/08/team-build-for-clickonce-application-with-bootstrapper/) entry the bootstrapper files are installed during the .NET Framework SDK/Visual Studio IDE install. It also shows the registry entries that are searched to look for the bootstrapper directory.

If one computer that does not have .Net Framework SDK/Visual Studio IDE installed(such as, build server), none of the registry key would be set.

> I did not find the registry keys on the build server as mentioned.

You can install .Net Framework SDK/Visual Studio IDE on the build server to get this registry key. If you don not want to install them, you could  manually set it up by following steps:

1. Copy the whole `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\SDK` folder from the local machine with Visual Studio IDE installed to the server.
2. creating the 14.0 registry key and adding the value:

For 86bits:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\GenericBootstrapper\14.0]
"Path"="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\SDK\Bootstrapper"
```

For 64 bits:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\GenericBootstrapper\14.0]
"Path"="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\SDK\Bootstrapper"
```

[image]

Note: Visual Studio must be restarted.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have SDK installed. I tried with bootstrapper false and that also fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have SDK installed on the server. I have updated the .csproj with

```
 <PropertyGroup>
     ...
    <BootstrapperEnabled>false</BootstrapperEnabled>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

That fixed the build.

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.